# What are naming rules for actions, tables and contracts?

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, action, table, contract-name

Since strings internally are converted to `uint64` for space efficiency on the eos.io blockchain what are the restrictions that need to be followed for:

- actions
- tables
- index identifiers (within `multi_index`'s)
- contract names
- anything else I've forgotten?

Comment: that's a good question. I'm new to c++. I'm basically following the default naming conventions from eos contract examples, that's usually lower_separated_by_underscores. There are some contracts outside eos that I see people doing CamelCase - I like it because we can understand which of them comes from eos and everything else is custom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Action names, table names, index names, account names, and everything else you use `N(foo)`, `"foo"_n`, or `eosio::name("foo")` for, have these rules. A contract belongs to an account.

- 12 characters max
- May contain: `a-z`, `1-5`, or `.`
- May not end with `.`

Names are encoded in base-32:

- `.` = 0
- `1-5` = 1 - 5
- `a-z` = 6 - 31

The 5 MSBs of the `uint64` contain the first character. Unused characters are replaced with `.` (0).

Comment: So contract names are exempt from these rules?

Comment: @MateiRadu Within your C++ code, you can call your contract whatever you like, but the account name that the contract is uploaded to must follow these rules.

Comment: @PhillipHamnett-EOS42 Thanks for clarifying