# How is the action data encoded?

Tags: action, transactions, api

Take for example this action belonging to a `newaccount` transaction:

```
{
      "account": "eosio",
      "name": "newaccount",
      "authorization": [{
          "actor": "eosio",
          "permission": "active"
        }
      ],
      "data": "0000000000ea305510c255191ba9b23f010000000100030a5d4c7f7d35c16028563c8ec58406bb084acf5ff95d386ada1de045b1d23dd501000000010000000100030a5d4c7f7d35c16028563c8ec58406bb084acf5ff95d386ada1de045b1d23dd501000000"
}
```

How is the `data` field encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action's ABI describes how to encode it. e.g. here's the [`newaccount` ABI](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/29799eae7bb919e480981e6abf110dfa75198f8d/contracts/eosio.bios/eosio.bios.abi#L57):

```
{
  "name": "newaccount",
  "base": "",
  "fields": [
    {"name":"creator", "type":"account_name"},
    {"name":"name",    "type":"account_name"},
    {"name":"owner",   "type":"authority"},
    {"name":"active",  "type":"authority"}
  ]
}
```

`account_name` is an alias for the built-in `name` type:

```
{
  "new_type_name": "account_name",
  "type": "name"
}
```

`authority` is another structure:

```
{
  "name": "authority",
  "base": "",
  "fields": [
    {"name":"threshold", "type":"uint32"},
    {"name":"keys",      "type":"key_weight[]"},
    {"name":"accounts",  "type":"permission_level_weight[]"},
    {"name":"waits",     "type":"wait_weight[]"}
  ]
}
```

The contract's ABI has defintions for all types it uses, except for the built-in types. e.g. `name` is a built-in type that contains up to 12 characters packed into a `uint64`. See [this answer](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/75/43) for `name`'s encoding.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/OracleChain/EOSDevHelper/blob/master/src/account/createaccountframe.cpp#L147-L151) is how *EOSDevHelper* serialize data in new account. In fact, it serializing `block num`, `block expiration`, `creator`, `permission` and `new name`. You can see details of it from link.